# nnet gives me error "NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 2)" in RStudio

Tags: r, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, data-science

I've been trying to run a neural network in RStudio to predict the answer of a bank marketing campaign, but for some reason I get the bellow error.

```
> bankData_net <- nnet(bankData[A,c(1:4)], Train_lab[A,], size=3, maxit=100, softmax=TRUE)
# weights:  23
Error in nnet.default(bankData[A, c(1:4)], Train_lab[A, ], size = 3, maxit = 100,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 2)
In addition: Warning message:
In nnet.default(bankData[A, c(1:4)], Train_lab[A, ], size = 3, maxit = 100,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

The database looks like the one bellow (these are only the first 10 rows to get an idea. The db has a few thousands of rows).

```
   age         job marital           education  y
1   56   housemaid married            basic.4y no
2   57    services married         high.school no
3   37    services married         high.school no
4   40      admin. married            basic.6y no
5   56    services married         high.school yes
6   45    services married            basic.9y no
7   59      admin. married professional.course no
8   41 blue-collar married             unknown yes
9   24  technician  single professional.course no
10  25    services  single         high.school no
```

And the bellow is the code I'm trying to run.

```
# save the data set in a variable
bankData = read.csv("data/bank-additional.csv", sep = ";")

# print first 10 rows of iris data
head(bankData, n=10)

# Remove variable "duration" which is not helpful 
newbankData <- subset(bankData, select = c(age, job, marital, education, y))


head(newbankData, n=10)


library(nnet)
# create train labels: convert the text bankData responses to numeric class labels
Train_lab <- class.ind(bankData$y)
# set seed for random number generator for repeatable results
set.seed(1)
# Create indexes for training (70%) and validation (30%) data
A <- sort(sample(nrow(bankData), nrow(bankData)*.7))
# train neural net 
# bankData[A,c(1:4)] is to select the first 4 variables as inputs
# size=5 for 5 hidden units, maxit=100 to train for 100 iterations
bankData_net <- nnet(bankData[A,c(1:4)], Train_lab[A,], size=3, maxit=100, softmax=TRUE)
# test
Yt <- predict(bankData_net, bankData[-A,c(1:4)], type="class")
# build a confusion matrix
conf.matrix <- table(bankData[-A,]$y, Yt)  
rownames(conf.matrix) <- paste("Actual", rownames(conf.matrix))
colnames(conf.matrix) <- paste("Pred", colnames(conf.matrix))
print(conf.matrix)
```

Please help me what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix this.

Comment: please post a sample of your data like `dput(head(bankData,200))`. Your piece of code works fine with the `iris` dataset for example. You can try to switch to the `formula` method, with `nnet(y~.,data=bankData[A,],size=3,maxit=100,softmax=T)` and see what happen

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. Bellow you can find the sample of the whole dataset in the gist as there are too many characters. https://www.codepile.net/pile/jQpRAPX9 I tried the formula you gave me, but it gives me the bellow error. ```> bankData_net <- nnet(y~.,data=bankData[A,],size=3,maxit=100,softmax=T)
Error in nnet.default(x, y, w, ...) : 
  'softmax = TRUE' requires at least two response categories```